# Is mining monero to a subaddress supported?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

I tried to send coin for a monero address and I tried also to mining this address  but an error message will be displayed : 
" Error: subaddress for mining reward is not yet supported!"
How can I support a monero address ?
Can you help me please !

Answer (score 1):

The message is quite clear: you're trying to mine to a subaddress, which is unsupported at the moment. A [Pull Request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3839) is open to add the feature, but the devs aren't agreeing apon the necessity of it.
If you want to solo-mine XMR, only use your main address and you'll be fine.
However, you should be able to ask a pool too use your subaddress to send your mining reward. If it's a pool issue, then get in touch with the pool owner and ask him to support transaction to subaddresses.

Comment: Clear , but why i've received XMR from the main address to the subaddress and that transaction passed correctly  , so which method should i use to let me generate and send xmr crypto between wallet addresses

Comment: If you are solo-mining then mine to your main address and then send the xmr to the subaddress. Are you mining on stagenet?

Comment: I am stagenet and i would like send xmr from subaddress to an external address (other subaddress )

Comment: Then first mine xmr to your main address. After that send xmr from main address to subaddress, and finally send xmr from subaddress to anywhere you want.

Comment: on the stagenet Network, i have enough xmr so no need to do mining and i would like send xmr from subaddress to an external monero address (other subaddress )

Comment: Then I should work just fine